# How to get data from a google spreadsheet that I only have view access to into google colaboratory

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-colaboratory, gspread

I have a link to a google spreadsheet that I do not own, but have view access to. Is there a way to get the data in that spreadsheet into the google colab notebook that I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the content of a Sheet with **View Only** access in **gspread** by using `open_by_key()` or `open_by_url()`.

### Example:

**Test Sheet:**

[image]

**Google Colab:**

```
!pip install --upgrade -q gspread

import gspread
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import auth
from google.auth import default
auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
# sh = gc.open_by_url("Insert Sheet URL here")
sh = gc.open_by_key("Insert Sheet key here")
worksheet = sh.worksheet("Sheet1")
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
```

**Result:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [gspread: Opening a Spreadsheet](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#opening-a-spreadsheet)

Comment: This question is in the close vote review queue, and you can review it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/31475938).